# how to check the exisitng data from database before inserting

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code and it does not work, it's not inserting into the database. Please help me fix this problem.

```
$orgexist = $_POST['orgName1'];

$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
$orgid          = $_POST['id'];
$orgnme         = $_POST['orgName1'];
$orgdesc        = $_POST['orgDesc'];
$orgcat         = $_POST['cat'];
$orgdept        = $_POST['coldept'];
$orgvis         = $_POST['vision'];
$orgmis         = $_POST['mision'];
//get the value of category from database
//echo $orgdept;
$dept           = "SELECT `col_id`, `col_description` FROM `college` WHERE `col_description` = '$orgdept'";
$deptresult     = mysql_query($dept);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($deptresult)) {
    $getcol = $rows['col_id'];
    //echo $getcol;
}

$sqlorg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `organization`");
while ($orgrows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlorg)) {
    //$dborgid = $orgrows['org_id'];
    $dborgnme = $orgrows['org_name'];
}

if ($dborgnme == $orgexist) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Organization Name Already Used by other Organization');
                history.back();
            </script>";
} else {
    $orginsrt = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `organization`(`org_id`,`org_name`,`org_desc`,`category`,`vision`,`mission`,`col_id`,`image`) VALUES ('$orgid','$orgexist','$orgdesc','$orgcat','$orgvis','$orgmis','$getcol','$image')");

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Proceed to next Step');</script>";
    //require ('orgsignup.php');
    header('Location:orgsignup2.php');
    //echo "Not in the Record";

}

}
```

Comment: It's probably not working because one of your POST fields has a single quote, and thus breaking your query. You should prepare with mysqli or PDO, or at least escape with mysql. Another piece of advice, instead of checking if something exists, just put a UNIQUE constrict on that column, and then if there are errors, you know that it didn't insert twice and you can show your javascript alert then.

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Comment: can i ask questios again? How can I create a view? like view user profile?

Answer (score 0):

You're using deprected functions, replace mysql_query by mysqli_query.

For more references see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: i have already solve that problem.. haha, thanks for the advice

Comment: i have already solve that problem.. haha, thanks for the advice